# Why is $(1-\cot 37^\circ)(1-\cot 8^\circ)=2.00000000\cdots$?

Tags: trigonometry

Apparently, 
$$(1-\cot 37^\circ)(1-\cot 8^\circ)=2.00000000000000000\cdots$$
Since it is a $2.0000000000\cdots$ instead of $2$, it isn't exactly $2$.
Why is that?

Comment: The RHS of the equality is exactly $2$.

Comment: Hint: $37^\circ + 8^\circ = 45^\circ$.

Comment: Not sure how to answer... perhaps you could explain why you believe $2.0000\cdots$ is not the same as $2$?

Comment: Use the addition law for $\cot(x+y)$, or the more familiar $\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}$.

Comment: OK, I hope my answer below is simpler than some I see here.

Answer (score 7):

Using various trigonometric identities, you should be able to show the left hand side is equal to $2$. The ones you will need are:
$$\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B,\quad \cos(-A)=\cos A,\quad \cos(45^\circ)=\sin(45^\circ)=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$$
as well as an understanding of what $\cot A$ means. The reason you have the answer of $2.000000\ldots$ (which I assume you got from WolfRamAlpha or similar) is because it's easier for a computer to just work out $\cot 37^\circ,\cot 8^\circ$ to any degree of accuracy and then solve by brute force. So the computer gets an answer of, for example, $2.000000$ correct to $6$ decimal places, but cannot be sure that the answer is exactly $2$.

Comment: You don't need to write $37^o$; you can write $37^\circ$.  (I changed it.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yeah, cheers. I always forget \ circ.

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{align}
1-\cot{\left(x\right)}
&=1-\frac{\cos{\left(x\right)}}{\sin{\left(x\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\sin{\left(x\right)}-\cos{\left(x\right)}}{\sin{\left(x\right)}}\\
&=-\sqrt{2}\frac{\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)}}{\sin{\left(x\right)}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
1-\cot{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)}
&=-\sqrt{2}\frac{\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)\right)}}{\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)}}\\
&=-\sqrt{2}\frac{\sin{\left(x\right)}}{\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Hence,

$$\begin{align}
\left(1-\cot{\left(x\right)}\right)\cdot\left(1-\cot{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)}\right)
&=\left[-\sqrt{2}\frac{\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)}}{\sin{\left(x\right)}}\right]\cdot\left[-\sqrt{2}\frac{\sin{\left(x\right)}}{\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)}}\right]\\
&=2.\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

$$
1 = \cot45^\circ = \cot(37^\circ+8^\circ) = \frac{\cot37^\circ\cot8^\circ-1}{\cot37^\circ+\cot8^\circ}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\cot37^\circ+\cot8^\circ = \cot37^\circ\cot8^\circ-1
$$
so
$$
2 = 1-\cot37^\circ-\cot8^\circ +\cot37^\circ\cot8^\circ=(1-\cot37^\circ)(1-\cot8^\circ).
$$

Comment: Definetely a sharp answer compared to the others (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,
$$\cot(x+y) = \frac{\cos(x+y)}{\sin(x+y)} = \frac{\cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y}{\sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y} = \frac{\cot x \cot y - 1}{\cot x + \cot y}$$

Now if $x = 37^\circ$, $y = 8^\circ$, then $\cot(x + y) = \cot 45^\circ = 1$ and

$$\begin{align}  \ \ \ \  1 & = \frac{\cot x \cot y - 1}{\cot x + \cot y} \\  \cot x + \cot y & = \cot x \cot y - 1 \\
   2 + \cot x + \cot y & = \cot x \cot y + 1 \\
 1 - \cot x - \cot y + \cot x \cot y  & = 2 \\
(1 - \cot x)(1 - \cot y) & = 2 \\
(1 - \cot 37^\circ)(1 - \cot 8^\circ) & = 2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$2.\dot 0$ is exacyly equal to 2

Comment: But how do you know it keeps repeating forever, as opposed to $(1-\cot37^\circ)(1-\cot8^\circ)$ being $2.00000\ldots00003$, with the "$3$" in the ten-thousandth place? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Because of David H's answer

Comment: But David H's answer doesn't say it's $2.\dot0$. ${}\qquad{}$